# Creating jump table of function pointers in C++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to create an array of function pointers in C++ that I can use as a jump table. The functions are all prototyped like

```
void(unsigned char*, int, int)
```

So I thought I would do

```
typedef void (*func)(unsighed char*, int, int);
```

and then

```
func tfunc[256];
```

And then set the individual elements like this:

```
tfunc[0]=func01;
```

But then I get "function call missing argument list; use '&myclass::func01'"

But then when I try

```
tfunc[0]=&myclass::func0;
```

I get "error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall myclass::* )(unsigned char *,int,int)' to 'myclass::tfunc'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible

I am confused.

I think I fixed it by adding MyClass:: in the header: tyepdef void (MyClass::*func...);

Comment: Please post a full compilable example of what you're trying to do, where you define stuff etc..

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use functions from a class.  Non-static class member functions have a hidden argument:  a pointer to the instance of the class.

Comment: Why not simply use virtual inheritance (vtable) with [tag:c++], which will properly sort this out for you?

Comment: @g-makulik: When you replace "virtual inheritance" by "virtual member functions", that's good advice.

Comment: @Sebastian Meant that at least (in contrast to static polymorphism/CRTP), thanks for clarifying ...

Comment: @g-makulik: With a jump table he might be doing a thing where a numeric ID triggers a particular function. Like a byte-code interpreter. That would not be appropriate use for virtual functions.

Comment: The functions are defined in the header: void func01(char* buf, int i int k); They are all non-static. They are just class member functions. These functions are not virtual. There's not going to be a derived class. IN the body of the class they are all like MyClass::func01(...){}.

Comment: @Ron _'The functions are defined in the header'_ Show this in your question then, be specific on your problems ...

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `std::function<void(unsigned char*, int, int)>` for your array of functions and appropriately bind your object using `std::bind()`:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::function<void(unsigned char*, int, int)> tfunc[256];
tfunc[0] = std::bind(&myclass::func0, this, _1, _2, _3);
```

Using `std::function<Signature>` is nicer than using function pointers in all cases because it allows to pass through necessary context, e.g., a pointer to an object. If you really mean to just call the function and you don't need an object, you can still use `std::function<...>` and you made your `func0` member `static` instead. In that case you could still use `std::bind()` but it isn't really needed:

```
struct myclass {
    static void func0(unsigned char*, int, int);
};
// ...
tfunc[0] = std::bind(&myclass::func0, _1, _2, _3);
tfunc[0] = &myclass::func0;
```

For the fans of dynamic polymorphism: internally `std::function<...>` has an inheritance hierarchy and any concrete initialization instantiates a derived class as needed. The only real differences are that you don't need to faff about creating a hierarchy and some implementations do clever things to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have an array of pointers to {static} functions or pointers to members, you will still need to pass the parameters when you call the function:

```
(*vector_of_functions[i])(param1, param2, param3);
```

The above is for standalone functions.  Executing a member via pointer to member method is left as an exercise to the reader (hint:  See C++ faq pointer to member).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a class member function into your array, the class member function should be declared `static`.

In case your class member function is not static, than you have to "bind" `this` to it, and it forces you to use the solution suggested by @Dietmar.